# ReferenceError: prettyPrint is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working through http://twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-form-validation/. I have got the project working except for adding an image at the end of the individual fields in my form.

my form looks like:

```
form id="registration-form" class="form-horizontal">
 <h2>Sample Registration form <small>(Fill up the forms to get register)</small></h2>
 <!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="Bob" class="input-xlarge" required="">

  </div>
</div>


<!-- <div class="form-form-control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="name">Your Name</label>
<div class="controls"><input class="input-xlarge" id="name" type="text" name="name" /></div>
</div>
<pre>-->    

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="LastName">Last Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Smith" class="input-xlarge" required="">

  </div>
</div>    


<div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Register</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button></div>
</form>    


<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script> 
<script>
addEventListener('load', function (event) { prettyPrint() }, false);                $(document).ready(function(){
            $('pre').addClass('prettyprint linenums');
                  });
            </script>
```

when the page loads in firebug I see:

```
ReferenceError: prettyPrint is not defined
```

referring to :

```
addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);
```

There are no other js errors.

PS I've added:

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

as above but am still getting the error. what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The error message pretty much says it all. What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

From: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html

> If you are calling prettyPrint via an event handler, wrap it in a function. Instead of doing
>
> `addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);`
>
> wrap it in a closure like
>
> `addEventListener('load', function (event) { prettyPrint() }, false);`
>
> so that the browser does not pass an event object to prettyPrint which will confuse it.

That being said, make sure

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

is loaded before your script is, even though it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've made the changes as you suggested, please see above but I'm still getting the same error - Bill